# Finding a vector in terms of a tensor

Tags: vectors, tensors

$T_{ij} = S_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ijk}V_k$ where $S_{ij}$ is symmetric. I need to find $S_{ij}$ and $V_k$ in terms of $T_{ij}$.

I found $S_{ij}$ by swapping i,j in the original equation and then adding the two together, but I am unsure on how to find $V_k$. What exactly is the 'inverse' of $\varepsilon_{ijk}$?

EDIT:
Think I've made some progress. Applying $\varepsilon_{ijq}$ to both sides gave me $\varepsilon_{ijq}T_{ij} = \varepsilon_{ijq}S_{ij} + 2\delta_{kq}V_k \implies \varepsilon_{ijq}T_{ij} = \varepsilon_{ijq}S_{ij} + 2V_q$.
Then swapping i,j and adding the two equations gave me $4V_k = \varepsilon_{ijk}(T_{ij} - T_{ji})$.
Can this be simplified further? (Also is it correct?)

Comment: $S$ will be the symmetric part of $T$ and the remainder will be the antisymmetric. So start with $S = (T + T^t)/2$.

Comment: Maybe it helps to know this representation works in 3d but not in 4d. If you write out what the matrix $\varepsilon_{ijk}V_k$ looks like, you'll see what $V$ needs to be for the antisymmetric part.